# Desktop icon spacing changed after monitor replacement

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, taskbar, icons

I just replaced my monitor with a TV Monitor of the same resolution and size (22" 1920x1080), but when I restarted Windows all the icons were in a different position.

I was expecting this kind of behaviour, since I'm a multimonitor user and I'm used to icons repositioning when monitor configuration changes.

The problem here is that there is a "strip" of blank space I cannot use anymore:

[image: All the space between the trashcan icon and the taskbar is not usable]

I googled online and I've found that there are some registry keys that controls the spacing between icons, but mine are still at the default value.

What happened? How can I use that space again?

Comment: try setting the spacing 1 smaller, move all icons to make them see the new default, swap back to default spacing, move them again. idk whether that would need reboots in between tweaks.

Comment: Check this: Where does Windows store icon positions? http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=fr&lc=fr&dlc=fr&docname=c01657439

Comment: @climenole Wrong link!?

Comment: Sorry for the wrong link. Here's the right one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/294116/where-does-the-system-store-the-icons-position